# ggplot2 legend for plot combining geom_bar and geom_point

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr

I am trying to make a plot to show the returns of various securities in a portfolio in a bar plot and then superimpose points over the bars indicating exposure to those securities. However, the legend I get completely ignores the points and only draws a legend for the bars.

#### To produce a dataframe with similar structure:

```
out<-data.frame(security=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"), avg_weight=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4), return_type=c(rep("systematic",4), rep("idiosyncratic",4)), return=rnorm(8))
```

#### Now, for plotting

```
g <- ggplot(data=out, aes(x=factor(security, levels=out$security), y=return))
g <- g + geom_bar(stat="identity", position="dodge", aes(fill=return_type))
g <- g + geom_point(aes(x=factor(security, levels=out$security), y=avg_weight))
g <- g + ggtitle("Systematic and Idiosyncratic Returns")
g <- g + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=70, hjust=1))
g + xlab("Security Description") + ylab("Return")
```

[image: Plot results]

#### How can I get a third entry in the legend, something like:

- Exposure

Answer (score 5):

ggplot generates legends only when you create an aesthetic mapping inside `aes`. This is usually done by mapping a data column to an aesthetic, like `fill`, `shape`, or `color`. Here we don't actually want to map `avg_weight` to an aesthetic, so we'll use `shape` as a "dummy" aesthetic, just to get the legend.

First, set a seed for data reproducibility:

```
# Set a seed for reproducibility
set.seed(4)
out<-data.frame(security=c("A", "B", "C", "D", "A", "B", "C", "D"), 
                avg_weight=c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4, 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4), 
                return_type=c(rep("systematic",4), rep("idiosyncratic",4)), return=cumsum(rnorm(8,0,0.1)))
```

In the code below, we add a "dummy" shape aesthetic to `geom_point` so that a shape legend will be generated. Then in `labs` we set `shape=NULL` so that the shape legend won't have a title.

```
ggplot(data=out, aes(x=security)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", aes(y=return, fill=return_type, group=return_type), position="dodge") +
  geom_point(aes(y=avg_weight, shape="Exposure")) + 
  ggtitle("Systematic and Idiosyncratic Returns") +
  theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=70, hjust=1)) +
  labs(x="Security Description", y="Return", shape=NULL) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks eipi10, very demystifying! :)