# Cannot change colors of lines in ggplot

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I have created the following plot using ggplot2:
[image]

Now I want the blue line to be a red dashed line and I want the red line to be a black line. I have used the following code to produce the plot:

```
ggplot(data=SLLN, aes(x=X1, y=X2, group=1)) + 
  geom_line(aes(colour = "Variable name A")) +                    
  geom_hline(aes(yintercept=theor_price, colour = "Variable name B")) +
  geom_point(size=1) +                       
  scale_x_log10(breaks = trans_breaks("log10", function(x) 10^x), #make log scale
  labels = trans_format("log10", math_format(10^.x))) +
  ylim(175, 250) +                           
  scale_colour_hue(name="", l=30)  +                  
  (lightness=30)
  scale_shape_manual(values=c(22,21)) +     
  scale_linetype_discrete() +
  xlab("xlab") + ylab("ylab") + 
  ggtitle("Title name") +     
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.background = element_rect(fill="transparent"), 
  legend.position=c(.85, .7))
```

When I remove aes() in geom_line and geom_hline, and change the argument of color to "black" and "red", the lines have the color I want, but they dissappear from the legend? How can I keep the image as it is now, so with the legend, and only change the colors of the lines and make the horizontal line dashed?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To get a legend, you need the color mappings to be inside `aes`. For a dashed line do: `geom_hline(aes(yintercept=1, colour = "Variable name B"), lty=2)`. To get the colors you want, get rid of the `scale_colour_hue` statement and add `scale_colour_manual(name="", values=c("black","red"))`.

Comment: The discussion in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44771265/496488) may be helpful for understanding the difference between putting things inside or outside `aes`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aes() function is for mapping variables to aesthetic attributes not for changing geoms' properties, you have to specify those outside aes() function, like this:

```
ggplot(data=SLLN, aes(x=X1, y=X2, group=1)) + 
       geom_line(aes(colour = "Variable name A")) +                    
       geom_hline(aes(yintercept=6, colour = "Variable name B"), linetype="dashed") +
       scale_color_manual(values = c("black","blue")) +
       ... (the rest of your code)
```