# Combined geom_bar and geom_point legend in ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggplotly

I am trying to get a combined bar + point chart with a legend for both bars different Indicators) and points (a change in the Indicator). I tried to follow along with [ggplot2 legend for plot combining geom_bar and geom_point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44770815/ggplot2-legend-for-plot-combining-geom-bar-and-geom-point) and introduced a shape into my geom_point (without doing that I could not get a legend for points).

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggthemes)
library(plotly)

set.seed(369)

obs <- 6

values1 <- c(round(100 + rnorm(obs) * 10, 2))
values2 <- c(round(100 + rnorm(obs) * 10, 2))

df <- data.frame(Year = rep(2014:2019, 2*2), 
                 value = c(rep(values1, 2), rep(values2, 2)),
                 Indicator = rep(c("Indicator1", "Indicator2"), each = obs * 2),
                 Type = rep(c("Bar", "Point"), each = obs))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(value))

bars <- df  %>%
  filter(Type == "Bar")

points <- df  %>%
  filter(Type == "Point")

pl <- p +
  geom_bar(data = bars,
           aes(fill = Indicator, group = Indicator, x = Year, y = value), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_point(data = points,  aes(x = Year, y = value, group = Indicator, fill = Indicator, shape = "Change"), position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  theme_tufte() 

p
ggplotly(pl, tooltip = c("value"))
```

ggplotly has the output I want, however the legend has a strange grouping. Is there a way to fix the legend in the chart below?

[image]

Comment: Found that there is an open issue on layered chart legends with ggplotly: https://github.com/ropensci/plotly/issues/1164 so this may be not possible at the moment

Answer (score 1):

there's probably a better way, but how's this:

```
library(tidyverse)

obs <- 6
values1 <- c(round(100 + rnorm(obs) * 10, 2))
values2 <- c(round(100 + rnorm(obs) * 10, 2))

df <- data.frame(Year = rep(2014:2019, 2*2), 
             value = c(rep(values1, 2), rep(values2, 2)),
             Indicator = rep(c("Indicator1", "Indicator2"), each = obs * 2),
             Type = rep(c("Bar", "Point"), each = obs))

bars   <- df  %>% filter(Type == "Bar")
points <- df  %>% filter(Type == "Point") %>% mutate(Year = 
                  ifelse(Indicator == "Indicator1", Year - 0.25, Year + 0.25))

 p <- ggplot(bars, aes(fill = Indicator, group = Indicator, x = Year, y = value)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 1) 
 p <- p + geom_point(data = points, mapping = aes(fill = Indicator, x = 
      Year, y = value), shape = 21) + labs(x = "value") + labs(y = "value")
 p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for taking a look at this.I get the same result when applying ggplot to the data frame, however try to run `ggplotly(p)`  and you will see that the legend geom_point is missing. Also the legend combines the bar chart and point to one and it is not something I need. The legend I need is in the plot I posted, however I need it to be clean without the parentheses grouping.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know `ggplotly()` , but building separate `geom_bar()` and `geom_point()` plots, and then using `get_legend()` to remove each legend, and then building them back with `plot_grid` with the full plot seems a decent option.

```
library(tidyverse)

obs <- 6
values1 <- c(round(100 + rnorm(obs) * 10, 2))
values2 <- c(round(100 + rnorm(obs) * 10, 2))

df <- data.frame(Year = rep(2014:2019, 2*2), 
             value = c(rep(values1, 2), rep(values2, 2)),
             Indicator = rep(c("Indicator1", "Indicator2"), each = obs * 2),
             Type = rep(c("Bar", "Point"), each = obs))

bars   <- df  %>% filter(Type == "Bar")
points <- df  %>% filter(Type == "Point") %>% mutate(Year = 
ifelse(Indicator == "Indicator1", Year - 0.25, Year + 0.25),
                                                 IndicatorChange = Indicator)

p1 <- ggplot(points, mapping = aes(fill = IndicatorChange, x = Year, y = value )) + labs(x = "value") + labs(y = "value") +
      geom_point(shape = 21)
p1_leg <- get_legend(p1)
p2 <- ggplot(bars, aes(fill = Indicator, group = Indicator, x = Year, y = value)) +
      geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") 
p2_leg <- get_legend(p2)

p_leg <- plot_grid(p1_leg, p2_leg, ncol = 1, nrow = 5) #toggle nrow to get right spacing between legends

p3 <-ggplot(bars, aes(fill = Indicator, group = Indicator, x = Year, y = value)) + geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge", width = 1) 
p3 <- p3 + geom_point(data = points, mapping = aes(fill = Indicator, x = Year, y = value), shape = 21) +
 labs(x = "value") + labs(y = "value")
p3 <- p3  + theme(legend.position="none")
p3
p <- plot_grid(p3, p_leg, ncol =2, nrow =2) #more toggling possible

p
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Yes, this is what I need, however this does not work with `ggplotly()`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this is what you want(although the font size of the legend should be modified):

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(ggthemes)
library(plotly)

set.seed(369)

obs <- 6

values1 <- c(round(100 + rnorm(obs) * 10, 2))
values2 <- c(round(100 + rnorm(obs) * 10, 2))

df <- data.frame(Year = rep(2014:2019, 2*2), 
                 value = c(rep(values1, 2), rep(values2, 2)),
                 Indicator = rep(c("Indicator1", "Indicator2"), each = obs * 2),
                 Type = rep(c("Bar", "Point"), each = obs))

p <- ggplot(df, aes(value))

bars <- df  %>%
  filter(Type == "Bar")

points <- df  %>%
  filter(Type == "Point")

points$Type1=paste(points$Indicator,"change",sep=",")


pl <- p +
  geom_bar(data = bars,
           aes(fill = Indicator, group = Indicator, x = Year, y = value), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_point(data = points,  
             aes(x = Year, y = value, group = Indicator, fill = Indicator, shape = "Change"), 
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  theme_tufte()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom")

pl <- p +
  geom_bar(data = bars,
           aes(fill = Indicator, group = Indicator,x = Year, y = value), stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
  geom_point(data = points,  
             aes(x = Year, y = value,shape = Type1), 
             position = position_dodge(width = 0.9)) +
  theme_tufte()+
  theme(legend.position="bottom",
        legend.title=element_blank())
p
```