# R plotly get legend show color but not split

Tags: r, plotly

My plotly lines are split by the interaction of two groups, and colored by another group. It is working except the legend still show all the interactions, which is unnecessary. I am currently using the code below:

```
dt%>%
plot_ly(x = ~x.center, y = ~y.center, z = ~z.center, type = 'scatter3d', mode = 'lines+markers', opacity = 1, marker = list(size = 2), 
        split = ~interaction(spreadsheet_row,participant.id), color = ~tasktype)
```

Just want the legend to be below (color by `tasktype`):
[image]

My data is big so I don't attached it here, but I believe it is a general config and can be tested with any other data.

Comment: TBMK there is no easy fix. But see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59613787/grouping-elements-in-legend-fails-with-ggplotly/59615148#59615148) answer and my answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69289623/avoid-legend-duplication-in-plotly-conversion-from-ggplot-with-facet-wrap/69290220#69290220) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69034684/how-to-eliminate-ggplotly-duplicate-legend-entries-when-using-more-than-one-geom) on how this could be achieved.

Comment: @stefan It there any method without using loop? It is counterintuitive and perhaps also inefficient to use loop for a single plot.

Comment: Hm. As you are dealing with a plotly object instead of a ggplotly (which my links refer too) there might be a better or more direct approach using `legendgroup`. But as far as I remember that involves adding the traces separately.